# Django: unit testing forms and KeyError

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, email

I'am unit testing a sign up form in django 1.5b, using the new custom user model. I want to test that my custom clean_email method raises a ValidationError when a new user tries to sign up with an already existing email, here is the clean method i wrote:`

```
def clean_email(self):

    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        user = MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
        raise forms.ValidationError("This email address already exists.")
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return email
```

The test code:

```
def test_clean_email(self):
    data = {'email': 'aaaa@gmail.com'}
    form = MyForm(data)
    actual   = form.errors['email']
    expected = [u'This email address already exists.']
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

I get this after running the test:

```
actual   = form.errors['email']
KeyError: 'email'
```

Comment: Did your MyForm hava a field named email?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `form.is_valid()` to get `form.errors` to be populated.

Comment: @iMom0 MyForm class actually has an email field, here it is:`email = forms.EmailField(
        label      = 'Email',
        initial    = 'Enter email address.',
    )`  @Daniel Roseman from django doc, Three types of cleaning methods are run during form processing. These are normally executed when you call the is_valid() method on a form. There are other things that can trigger cleaning and validation (accessing the errors attribute or calling full_clean() directly), but normally they won’t be needed.

Comment: Erm, that's good. You still need to call `form.is_valid()` first.